# Bernoulli Distribution (PMF) of random variables X,Y

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables

A fair coin is tossed three times, let **X** be the number of cases in which the HEAD is obtained, and **Y** be the **absolute** value of difference between the number of HEAD and the number of TAIL. Seek the distribution law (that is, the **PMF**) of random variables (X,Y).
(Hint: First consider the discrete value range of X and Y (0 to 3 each), and the Bernoulli trial, and list all the PMF’s)

Comment: Well? How far did you get with this? And where did you got stuck? Btw, do not write that in a comment, but in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

$\mathbf{Y}=\left|\mathbf{X}-\left(3-\mathbf{X}\right)\right|=\left|2\mathbf{X}-3\right|$
so $\mathbf{X}$ determines $\mathbf{Y}$.